# Unresolved external symbols when trying to compile Sandboxie from GitHub

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to compile the latest version of Sandboxie from https://github.com/sandboxie/sandboxie as the version I'm using doesn't run on Windows 10 2004. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and the MS Windows Device Driver Kit (DDK) 7.1.0 as mentioned in the build instructions. But I'm now getting `unresolved external symbol` errors while compiling the `SBoxDll` project.

I'm wondering if I need to add a reference or something as it mentions external symbols, but I don't write C++ and I've no idea where to start. I don't want to make any changes I just want to compile it to see if it will run on Win 10 2004. Is anybody able to tell me how to get it to resolve these symbols please?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SboxDll, Configuration: SbieRelease x64 ------
1>     Creating library C:\Users\Removed\Documents\VSProjects\sandboxie-master\Bin\x64\SbieRelease\SbieDll.lib and object C:\Users\Removed\Documents\VSProjects\sandboxie-master\Bin\x64\SbieRelease\SbieDll.exp
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>advapi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>com.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>cred.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsnicmp
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol towlower
1>callsvc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol towlower
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol towlower
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol towlower
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol towlower
1>support.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memcpy referenced in function SbieDll_FormatMessage
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>taskbar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>sbieapi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>secure.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>obj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>ole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>rpcrt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>ipstore_impl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>net.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guiprop.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>iphlp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guidlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guienum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guimisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guimsg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>gdi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>gui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>guidde.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>dllmem.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>callsvc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>com.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>cred.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>crypt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>ole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>rpcrt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>iphlp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>ipstore_impl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>net.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>guimisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>guiprop.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>includes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>gdi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>guidlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>guienum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>dllmem.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>callsvc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>com.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>cred.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>custom.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>net.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>com.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>taskbar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>gdi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>com.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcschr
1>com.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _itow referenced in function Com_Trace
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _itow
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>taskbar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>cred.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>guidde.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncmp
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>sysinfo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>rpcrt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>secure.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>ipstore_enum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>obj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>guidde.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>guimsg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>gdi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>gui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>guicon.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>cred.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp
1>secure.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcsstr referenced in function Secure_Init
1>support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>guimsg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>custom.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsstr
1>custom.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memcmp referenced in function Custom_Avast_SnxHk_LdrGetProcedureAddress
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
1>guimisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcslwr
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>ole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>secure.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>guihook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>guititle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>dllhook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>gdi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>ole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>ipc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsrchr
1>dllpath.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcstol referenced in function Pattern_Match3
1>net.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcstol
1>scm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>terminal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>guienum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>proc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>sbieapi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy
1>file.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wtoi referenced in function File_InitCopyLimit
1>sh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wtoi
1>support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wtoi
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wtoi
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strchr referenced in function Gui_GetClassNameA
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strchr
1>guiclass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strncmp referenced in function Gui_CreateClassNameA
1>guidde.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcstoul referenced in function Gui_DDE_COPYDATA_Received
1>guidlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __chkstk referenced in function GUI_CreateDialogTemplate1
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tolower referenced in function Ldr_GetProcAddr_2
1>ldr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _stricmp referenced in function Ldr_MyDllCallbackA
1>net.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol iswctype referenced in function WSA_InitBlockedPorts
1>support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol iswctype
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strstr referenced in function Sxs_CheckManifestForCreateProcess
1>sxs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strlwr referenced in function Sxs_CheckManifestForCreateProcess
1>D:\Users\Removed\Documents\VSProjects\sandboxie-master\Bin\x64\SbieRelease\SbieDll.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 26 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Those are functions in the CRT (C runtime library).  Check that 'Ignore all default libraries' is not set in the Linker Input options in the project property pages.

Comment: Thank you, `/NODEFAULTLIB` is set. I found a comment from Hans Passant saying it's normally used to suppress an important warning. My concern is removing this when the developer enabled it for a reason could cause another problem? I've added `vcruntime.lib` and `libucrt.lib` to the linker and now have a smaller list of unresolved symbols: _chkstk, __GSHandlerCheck, __security_check_cookie, __isa_available, __xp_a, __xp_z, __crt_debugger_hook referenced in  __acrt_call_reportfault and __report_rangecheckfailure referenced in _wsetlocale_nolock. Any idea which libs are needed for these please?

Comment: I resolved those by adding `LIBCMTD.lib`. Thank you both for your help.